# how to create a django app that performs a google search

Tags: python, django

I want to make a Django app that searches on google a string and then saves the html page.

so far I managed to

create this

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">





<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>my search engine</h1>
    <h3>Pressing search will run a google search for 'lallero search', then the code will scrape the first 5 links in that google search and store the corresponding html.</h3>
    <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About page</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="{% url 'search' %}">



    <input type='submit' value='search' class="btn btn-primary">



    </form>
</div>
```

that searches on google a very specific string and it is just a press button.
I would like to add a form where I can write the string I want to search and then pass it as input to my "search" function

so far I came out with this

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>my search engine</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About page</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="{% url 'search' %}">

  <input type="search" value='lallero search' class="form-control rounded" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"
    aria-describedby="search-addon" />
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">search</button>
</div>
```

but I do not know how to pass the string I write as input to the function.

any advice?

--------------------update

Following comments, I put the SearchForm into a utils file that I import and then I changed my search function to

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():  # this will validate your form
        search_text = form.cleaned_data["search"]  # now you can access input
    urls = searchWeb(num=5, stop=5, query_string=search_text)

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=getSavePage, args=(url,)) for url in urls]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    return JsonResponse(urls, safe=False)
```

I changed my template to

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">






<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>my search engine</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About page</a>
    <br>
    <br>

    <form action="{% url 'search' %}">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {{ form.as_p }} <!-- This will create a text input with attributes -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

I get an error as the form status is unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following @berkeeb answer I changed the code in this way.

I created a forms.py file with:

```
from django import forms


class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=255, label="search")
```

in my template (home.html) I used:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>my search engine</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'about' %}">About page</a>
    <br>
    <br>
        <form action="{% url 'search' %}">
    <label for="search_text">Your search: </label>
    <input id="search_text" type="text" name="search_text">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</div>
```

and finally in the search function I wrote:

```
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    search_text = form.data["search_text"]  # now you can access input
    urls = searchWeb(num=5, stop=5, query_string=search_text)

    threads = [threading.Thread(target=getSavePage, args=(url,)) for url in urls]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    return render(request, "engine/search.html", {"search": urls})
```

basically I had to remove the validation part of the form as I kept receiving status unknown.

Answer (score 3):

Briefly, in your view that is been invoked by the form can access your form data with `request.GET`, `request.POST`. Since its search functionality get method should be used. And your input will be in your querysting something like `www.yourdomain.com/search-view?search=input`.Instead of accessing it by  `request.GET["search"]`, django forms will be a better choice. In your case

```py
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(required=True, max_lenght=255, label="Search")
```

And you can use it in your template as

```html
<form action="{% url 'search' %}">
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {{ form.as_p }} <!-- This will create a text input with attributes -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And you can use it in your view;

```py
from . import SearchForm

form = SearchForm(request.GET) 
if form.is_valid(): # this will validate your form 
    search_text = form.cleaned_data["search"] # now you can access input
```

Please check out [working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#working-with-forms).

Edit:

```py
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is valid now you can process your data")
            # return a response or render a different template
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/redirect-url/') 
        # if not render the form back
            return render(request, 'your_template.html', {"form": form})
    # Assume post method is not allowed
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed()
```

Comment: edit my question following your comment, I get an error

Comment: Can you share your error trace back or your code block?

Comment: urls = searchWeb(num=5, stop=5, query_string=search_text)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'search_text' referenced before assignment ... this is because the statement form.is_valid() return false

Comment: So if your form is not valid then you have a bad input from your text input. You can decide how to validate your form based on your input and how to act if its not valid, occasionally you return your form to your template and render your error messages.

Comment: there is no input. the app return this erros as soon as I run the server

Comment: I have to see your view to trace what is going on in your code but I edited my answer and add and extra view so can see an example how to use forms in your view or try this code block in your view if it works then just replace `print` statement with your own logic. Also don't forget to import relevant method and classes.

Comment: I have made some changes. and now I am at least able to display the form. code is here  https://github.com/bruvio/google-search-app/tree/customsearchbar